# Automatically convert string concatenation to template literals

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, code-conversion, template-literals, template-strings

I have a code base with many strings built via string concatenation. Is there a automated method for replacing all instances of string concatenation with [templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)? For example:

```
const a = 'b ' + c;
// becomes:
const a = `b ${c}`;
```

A script-based solution would be awesome. An editor plugin would be even better. (I am using Visual Studio Code.)

Comment: ESLint should be able to do that.

Comment: Do you mean to say that you want a script to parse your JS code and detect and replace with template literals wherever you'd had joined strings using `+`?

Comment: @Aakash Verma yes

Comment: @idmean thank you, this is the rule I was looking for: http://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-template

Answer (score 5):

This can be done with eslint. See rule: http://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-template.

The following will run a single rule on the `src` directory and fix any errors. The rule is a string encoded JSON-like value. The values in the array are 0 - ignore, 1 - warn, 2 - error.

`eslint ./src --rule '{prefer-template:[2]}' --fix`

Similarly, if you are using TypeScript `tslint` can do something similar, although it doesn't seem to be able to just have a single rule specified:

`tslint --config ./tslint.json --project ./tsconfig.json --fix`

Comment: Glad it worked out for you! It'd be great if you could help beginners like me by elaborating on how to use it. Thanks!